# How to create page with parameters in gatsbyJS dynamically?

Tags: gatsby

I want a route like: `/blog/:blogId/:slug`

I tried this in my `gatsby-node.js` -

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  createPage({
      path: "/blog/",
      matchPath: "/blog/:blogId/:slug",
      component: path.resolve("src/components/layouts/SingleBlogPageLayout.jsx"),
  })
}
```

It works perfectly in `gatsby develop` but showing issues in `gatsby build`

The error is:

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 6.584s

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  247 | 
  248 | 
> 249 |       var store = didStoreComeFromProps ? props.store : contextValue.store;
      | ^
  250 |       var childPropsSelector = useMemo(function () {
  251 |         // The child props selector needs the store reference as an input.
  252 |         // Re-create this selector whenever the store changes.


  WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of null

  - connectAdvanced.js:249 ConnectFunction
    node_modules/react-redux/es/components/connectAdvanced.js:249:1
```

Comment: Did you take a look at https://gatsby.dev/debug-html, like the error says? The most common reason for broken production builds is when you're using browser globals like `window` (or a library you're importing uses it). This fails in Gatsby prod builds, because they're server-side rendered and `window` will be undefined.

Comment: Yes, I did and explicitly checked for the common error. But no luck :(
Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think, your issue is in your redux setup. Did you add your redux wrapper in both `gatsby-browser.js` & `gatsby-ssr.js` file?

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved the issue. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your redux wrapper in both `gatsby-browser.js`& `gatsby-ssr.js` file

```
Import wrapWithProvider from "./wrap-with-provider"

export const wrapRootElement = wrapWithProvider
```

Hope this works

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved the issue. :)

I put the wrapper in the browser only but not in the ssr. Now I put in the both sections, it works. :)